# Update Multiple selection dropdown list for a single data in a table

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive

I have a list of students that for each one of them I can assign roles to them in a multiselect dropdown list, buut when I select the roles one or two it changes for all the students in the table, but each student is indivisual so if I assign role assistant to a student it should be only for that one.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="S in SList">
                <td width="33%">{{S}}</td>
                <td width="33%">
                    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" options="Categories" selected-model="CategoriesSelected" checkboxes="true">
                    </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </div>
    <script src="../../javascript/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="../../javascript/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../javascript/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../../javascript/AngularControllers/Controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="../../javascript/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
</html>
```

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER that i have already pasted the part related to multidropdownlist

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
app.controller('multiselectdropdown', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    //Loading data to the table
    var urlBase = '../Myhandler.ashx';

    this.getSList = function () {
        $http.get(urlBase, {
            params: {
                plug: "MyClassname",
                cmd: "MyMethodName"
            }
        })
        .success(function (Students) {
            $scope.SList = Students;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
        });
    }

    this.getSList();
    //define object 
    $scope.CategoriesSelected = [];
    $scope.Categories = [];
    $scope.dropdownSetting = {
        scrollable: true,
        scrollableHeight : '200px'
    }
    //fetch data from database for show in multiselect dropdown
    $http.get('/home/getcategories').then(function (data) {
        angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, index) {
            $scope.Categories.push({ id: value.CategoryID, label: value.CategoryName });
        });
    })
    //post or submit selected items from multiselect dropdown to server
    $scope.SubmittedCategories = [];
    $scope.SubmitData = function () {
        var categoryIds = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.CategoriesSelected, function (value, index) {
            categoryIds.push(value.id);
        });

        var data = {
            categoryIds: categoryIds
        };

        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/home/savedata",
            data:JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(function (data) {
            $scope.SubmittedCategories = data.data;
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Error');
        })
    }
}])
```

THIS IS MY PROBLEM: if I select options in a dropdownlist it changes for all the record in the table. how can I make the changes for only the student I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All your dropdown seem to share the same model

```
selected-model="CategoriesSelected"
```

You have to use a own list for each Student, e.g.

```
selected-model="S.CategoriesSelected"
```

which you then have to initialize for each student

Comment: Thanks but would you please help how can I make this change in tha controller?

Comment: I do not know where your SList is defined, but there you have to iterate over S in SList and add S.CategoriesSelected =[];

Comment: I do not surely what you want to do in the Submit, there you have to post the data for all Students or only one student? You there need to post S.CategoriesSelected of course, but do not know enough over your Application

Comment: change the success part to the following: .success(function (Students) { $scope.SList = Students; $scope.SList.forEach(function(student){student.CategoriesSelected=[]}) })

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make CategoriesSelected as an object with student names as key.

```
$scope.SList = ['student1', 'student2', 'student3'];
$scope.CategoriesSelected = {};
```

then in HTML:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="S in SList">
    <td width="33%">{{S}}</td>
    <td width="33%">
      <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" options="Categories" selected-model="CategoriesSelected[S]" checkboxes="true"></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I just updated my question, I aded     //Loading data to the table
in the controller part to show how I fill teh student part, I read it from the database and I load it to the table in a ng-repeat

in this case I have my $scope.SList in .success and when I mplement the solution it does not let me to select at all